# If controller should execute if the last sampler's duration assertion gets failed - Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I have a testplan with if controllers.I have added duration assertion for each samplers.But I want my If controller to execute if the last sampler's duration assertion only gets failed.If other assertions gets failed,the If controller need not to be executed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following [__groovy() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__groovy) as the condition:

```
${__groovy(ctx.getPreviousResult().getAssertionResults().findAll(assertionResult -> assertionResult.getName() == 'Duration Assertion' && assertionResult.isFailure()).size() > 0,)}
```

where `ctx` stands for [JMeterContext](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterContext.html) class instance, see [Top 8 JMeter Java Classes You Should Be Using with Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/top-8-jmeter-java-classes-you-should-be-using-with-groovy) article for more information on this and other [JMeter API](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/index.html) shorthands available for the [JSR223 Test Elements](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223)

Comment: i am getting following error when pasting the above syntax in IF controller.

Comment: javax.script.ScriptException: org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
Script532.groovy: 1: unexpected token: -> @ line 1, column 71.
   lts().findAll(assertionResult -> asserti
                                 ^

Caused by: org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
Script532.groovy: 1: unexpected token: -> @ line 1, column 71.
   lts().findAll(assertionResult -> asserti